# Why does the C# compiler allow an explicit cast between IEnumerable<T> and TAlmostAnything?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, compiler-errors

The following code gives you a compiler error, as you'd expect:

```
List<Banana> aBunchOfBananas = new List<Banana>();

Banana justOneBanana = (Banana)aBunchOfBananas;
```

However, when using `IEnumerable<Banana>`, you merely get a runtime error.

```
IEnumerable<Banana> aBunchOfBananas = new List<Banana>();

Banana justOneBanana = (Banana)aBunchOfBananas;
```

Why does the C# compiler allow this?

Comment: A list of things is not a single thing.

Comment: Not allowed with value types, though.

Comment: This also apples(ok applies) to IList<Banana>. That's what made the whole interface vs concrete class click for me in the answers below.

Comment: very very bad design from MS. The answers are not convincing to have this feature..

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I would suppose it's because `IEnumerable<T>` is an interface where some implementation *could* have an explicit cast to `Banana` - no matter how silly that would be.

On the other hand, the compiler knows that `List<T>` can't be explicitly cast to a `Banana`.

Nice choice of examples, by the way!

*Adding an example to clarify.* Maybe we'd have some "enumerable" that should always contain **at most** a single `Banana`:

```
public class SingleItemList<T>:Banana, IEnumerable<T> where T:Banana {
    public static explicit operator T(SingleItemList<T> enumerable) {
        return enumerable.SingleOrDefault();
    }

    // Others omitted...
}
```

Then you **could** actually do this:

```
IEnumerable<Banana> aBunchOfBananas = new SingleItemList<Banana>();
Banana justOneBanana = (Banana)aBunchOfBananas;
```

As it's the same as writing the following, which the compiler is perfectly happy with:

```
Banana justOneBanana = aBunchOfBananas.SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: You can't do this - it won't find the operator. An example would be `class SingleBanana : Banana, IEnumerable<Banana>`. This is why this only works for interfaces - because if both types are classes, this can be determined to be impossible at compile time.

Comment: @Random832 Good catch, but in fact your class signature won't work either (you can't have an explicit conversion to a base class). I've updated my answer with a version that does as intended.

Comment: Er, my point was you can't use operator overloading _at all_ for this. The reason it works is because a derived class object is _inherently_ convertible to the base class.

Comment: @Random832 Right. That's what the example illustrates. That there is a way to have this work with something that implements `IEnumerable<T>`. Whether the example is contrived or trivial is irrelevant with regard to *why* it works.

Comment: But my point was you don't need the operator at all - an empty class [other than the interface implementation] with the signature I gave in my first comment is sufficient.

Comment: @Random832 I understand, but the explicit conversion operator is there to illustrate the point. I could have written the example with an empty class inheriting from `Banana` and implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, but I felt this was more clear.

Comment: The first sentence still talks about explicit conversion operators, and still is wrong.  And the explicit operator code example is confusing.  The runtime check is for inheritance, not an operator.

Answer (score 29):

When you say `Y y = (Y)x;` this cast says to the compiler "trust me, whatever `x` is, at runtime it can be casted to a `Y`, so, just do it, okay?"

But when you say

```
List<Banana> aBunchOfBananas = new List<Banana>();
Banana justOneBanana = (Banana)aBunchOfBananas;
```

the compiler can look at the definitions for each of these concrete classes (`Banana` and `List<Banana>`) and see that there is no `static explicit operator Banana(List<Banana> bananas)` defined (remember, an explicit cast must be defined in either the type being casted or the type being casted to, this is from the spec, section 17.9.4). It knows at compile time that what you're saying can not ever be true. So it yells at you to stop lying.

But when you say

```
IEnumerable<Banana> aBunchOfBananas = new List<Banana>();
Banana justOneBanana = (Banana)aBunchOfBananas;
```

well, now the compiler doesn't know. It very well could the case that whatever `aBunchOfBananas` happens to be at run time, its concrete type `X` could have defined `static explicit operator Banana(X bananas)`. So the compiler trusts you, like you asked it to.

Comment: Maybe because you didn't mention you make a distinction between classes and integers? Not knowing that, your first (X and Y) and second example are exactly the same.

Comment: Yes this is downvoted... it's wrong.  Conversion operators can't be found at runtime (unless the `dynamic` keyword gets involved).  Have another downvote.

Comment: This part is wrong: *It very well could [be] the case that whatever `aBunchOfBananas` happens to be at run time, its concrete type `X` could have defined `static explicit operator Banana(X bananas)`.*

Answer (score 16):

It may be because the compiler *knows* that `Banana` does not extend `List<T>`, but that there's a possibility that some object which implements `IEnumerable<T>` may also extend `Banana` and make that a valid cast.

Comment: Sad to see the only correct answer, posted among the first, not get as many upvotes.  Perhaps a short code snippet would help.

Answer (score 1):

According to language spec (6.2.4)
"The explicit reference conversions are:
 From any class-type S to any interface-type T, provided S is not sealed and provided S does not implement T
...
The explicit reference conversions are those conversions between reference-types that require run-time checks to ensure they are correct..."

So compiler doesn't check interface realization during compilation. It does CLR in runtime. It checks metadata trying to find realization in class or among its parents. I dunno why it behaves like this. Probably it takes a lot of time. So this code compiles correctly:

```
public interface IInterface
{}

public class Banana
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        Banana banana = new Banana();

        IInterface b = (IInterface)banana;
    }
}
```

In other hand if we try to cast banana to class, compiler checks its metadata and throw an error:

```
 FileStream fs = (FileStream)banana;
```